# How to use sequalize.literal IF statement in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I need to use sequalize.literal in my node js code.
What I need to do is use an If  else statement inside that sequalize literal,
Are there any references for this?
I tried in the below way, but node js returning that syntax is wrong. Can someone helop me to correct the syntax?

sequelize.literal('if(`userId` is not null, `yes`,`no`) as `status`')

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to use a MySQL case statement inside of a sequelize subquery.

The relevant MySQL docs are for cases statements can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), and the sequelize docs for sub queries can are [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html).

Here's an example similar to the query in the original question.

```
let {
        Sequelize,
        DataTypes,
    } = require('sequelize')

async function run () {
    let sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
            host:       'localhost',
            dialect:    'mysql',
            logging:    console.log
        })

    let Comment = sequelize.define('comment', {
            userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            comment: DataTypes.STRING
        })

    await sequelize.sync({ force: true })

    await Comment.bulkCreate([{
            comment: 'Hello'
        }, {
            userId: 42,
            comment: 'This is it.'
        }, {
            userId: 128,
            comment: 'Breakfast of the day.'
        }])
    
    let comments = await Comment.findAll({
            attributes: [
                'id',
                'comment',
                [ sequelize.literal('(case when userId is not null then "yes" else "no" end)'), 'status' ]
            ]
        })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(comments, null, 2))

    await sequelize.close()
}

run()
```

This outputs

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "Hello",
    "status": "no"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "comment": "This is it.",
    "status": "yes"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "comment": "Breakfast of the day.",
    "status": "yes"
  }
]
```